# Prepend text to form on submission with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to add "https://" to a form on submission, without it appearing the text submission box. So far I have a script:

```
<script>
    function formSubmit(){
        var x=document.getElementById(“formname”);
        for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            if(x.elements.item(i).id == 'q' && x.elements.item(i).value != "" ) 
                x.elements.q.value='https://'+x.elements.item(i).value;
            document.getElementById("formname").submit();
        }
</script>
```

and the form:

```
<form name="formname" method="GET" action="http://google.com/search" onsubmit="return (this.q.value == '') ? false : true; >
    <input type="text" name="q" size="32" maxlength="256" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnG" value="Search" />
```

but can't figure it out. anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: may need to change document.getElementById(“formname”); to document.getElementByName(“formname”);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely won't want to try submitting the form again in your function; after it finishes calling, it'll continue to submit as long as you don't `return false`.

Your function should just be:

```
function formSubmit(){
    var e=document.forms.formname.q;
    if(e.value){
        e.value='https://'+e.value;
    } return true;
}
```

And your form's `onsubmit` attribute...

```
<form onsubmit="return this.q.value != '' && formSubmit()">
```

Comment: hmm, nothing is happening when I click Search. should it be this.e.value? When I change it to that, it submits, but doesn't append...

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake with the form's `onsubmit` part. See the updated answer.